# Backup stock HTC Desire ROM with Unrevoked

Tags: htc-desire, custom-roms, rooting, unrevoked

I want to play with different ROM's for HTC Desire (which is still under warranty). Based on my understanding, in order to keep the warranty and still play with custom ROM's, the following steps are required.

1. Root the Phone with Unrevoked Method
2. Take a backup of the stock ROM
3. Restore a custom ROM
4. And when warranty is required restore the stock ROM from backup

Am I going in the correct direction?. If yes where can I find the guides to perform all of the above mentioned steps.

**NOTE: I don't want to lose the warranty of the phone. I know it will get void once I root it but then there should be options to unroot the device and get it back to factory settings. **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your steps are correct and I would add to the end of the list to remove the rooting as well.

Two sites that will provide the majority of the information you are looking for are [Android Forums](http://androidforums.com) and [XDA Developers](http://www.xda-developers.com/)

**Edits:**

Video and Guide - [HOW TO ROOT THE HTC DESIRE (UNREVOKED METHOD)](http://theunlockr.com/2010/09/20/how-to-root-the-htc-desire-unrevoked-method/)

Video and Guide - [HOW TO LOAD A CUSTOM ROM ON THE HTC DESIRE](http://theunlockr.com/2010/09/21/how-to-load-a-custom-rom-on-the-htc-desire-2/)

In order to backup your stock ROM, after you root your phone and before you install a custom ROM you will need to install "ROM Manager" (available in the Market). After "ROM Manager" is installed and you start it you will need to install ClockworkMod Recovery (the first option in ROM Manager). Once the custom recovery is installed, look further down ROM Manager's menu and you will see an option to backup your current ROM, which is what you want to do.

Once the backup is made copy the file to your computer so you have a secondary backup. In fact, copy the entire contents of your SD Card to your computer because sometimes the card is formatted or wiped during the install of some ROMs.

That will get you started but definitely do a lot of research so you understand what you are doing and more importantly what options are available. There are probably 30 ROMs available for the Desire and they all offer something different. You'll have to find the one that you like the most in order to get the best experience.

Comment: can you point me to the exact guide locations and also how do I take a backup of the stock ROM

Answer (score 2):

If you root or install a custom ROM you void your warranty.  It doesn't matter if you undo it.  You might be less likely to be caught, but that depends on the carrier/manufacturer.  And if you're running a custom ROM and your phone breaks, you will often not be able to restore the backup (depending on how it broke).  If you want to keep your warranty, don't do anything that is against its terms.